# Update Value of Jquery Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

How to update the value of jquery cookie ?

```
$.cookie('location', area_text)
```

area_text value get changed again and again, but when i logged the value of location, it gives me the previous value. How can i update it. ?

Even if I try to set it null like as follow. and check the log it still gives me the previous value.

```
$.cookie('location', null)
```

Beside this, when I do `$.removeCookie("location")` it returns false.

Thanks

Comment: Are you checking the cookie in the same domain as you're updating it?

Comment: use path: '/' , Check my answer for more details to fix this issue

Comment: @Barmar yes i am checking it on the same domain

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The value of cookie is getting updated as you can see in the image.

I hope something else you are doing wrong.

```
path: '/'
```

Define the path where the cookie is valid. By default the path of the cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard browser behavior). If you want to make it available for instance across the entire domain use path: '/'. Default: path of page where the cookie was created.

So define in this way

```
$.cookie('location', 'value', { path: '/' });
```

so that it will be accessible everywhere

Comment: even if I set the path I am still unable to update the value, and i am amazed why $.removeCookie is returning false